# Elapsed time timer stops when audio is played

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label showing elapsed time of a walk and an audio player on the same screen. How can I keep the elapsed time timer running when the audio is playing? As soon as the audio starts playing the timer stops and doesn't restart even if the audio is stopped.

Elapsed time timer -

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(eachSecond) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And the timer governing the audio (in a different class) -

```
-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{
float minutes = floor(lroundf(value)/60);
float seconds = lroundf(value) - (minutes * 60);
NSInteger roundedSeconds = lroundf(seconds);
NSInteger roundedMinutes = lroundf(minutes);

NSString *time = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld", (long)roundedMinutes, (long)roundedSeconds];
return time;
}

-(void)setCurrentAudioTime:(float)value{
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer setCurrentTime:value];


}

-(NSTimeInterval)getCurrentAudioTime{
return [self.backgroundMusicPlayer currentTime];
}

-(float)getAudioDuration{
return [self.backgroundMusicPlayer duration];
```